# Java port descriptor

Tags: java, android, networking, port

I have made a port scanner in java which works correctly, now all i would like to have is a way of telling my user what the port is being used for. The desired method would ideally be something that takes the input as an int representing the port and gives back the description of that port. Such as the input 53 would result in the output "DNS". How would i achieve something like this other than plugging in predetermined data.

Comment: You have a problem here... You say 53, fine, but DNS is 53/UDP or 53/TCP. TCP is not the norm for DNS. In C you would use `getservbyport()` to obtain this information, not sure for Android...

Comment: Well android is java...so however it is done in java it is done the same in android unless it has to do with UI stuff.

Comment: That is the problem, here you don't deal with UI stuff, but with pretty basic low level stuff, from a Java point of view -- ie, OS stuff. I don't know whether Java proper has an API for this, but maybe Android has? Just look how long it took for Java proper to get filesystem stuff (partially) right in Java 7!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think there is any API in the core Java or Android that provides this information. I suspect you will have to provide the predetermined list yourself. This should not be difficult: you can grab the list from a number of places, including http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers